# BCP SQL Server into a table

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to BCP a file into a table that has the same columns as the file being brought in

BCP command

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'BCP [CMS_Data].[dat].[SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report_RAW] in "\\FileShare\datafeeds\CMS_ResearchStatistics\Temp\SNP-2019-02\SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report.csv" -t"|" -T -c -F2 -S MSSQLSERVER'
```

I am getting this error

> Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.

I am using F2 to skip the header row the error states I need a in, out or format but the in is clearly there. This must be some other issue I am not seeing. This code worked prior. I changed the F2 to F18 since that is where the data started on the file. Since that seemed like an issue I moved data to line 2 but now it does not work there either.

Comment: Simplify your problem. Start by using a command prompt and running bcp directly so you can avoid the tsql issues and you can better see the information bcp generates. Does that work? And perhaps reconsider the use of xp_cmdshell in this fashion.

Comment: This shouldn't be caused by any contents of the file but by the fact that `bcp` can't parse its command line (it's extremely finicky that way). If necessary retype the command to ensure no invisible spacing characters or strange encoding has crept in. Also try `-F 2` (with an explicit space), even though that should not matter, and try changing the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the data set from https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Downloads/2019/Feb/SNP-2019-02.zip

I converted the xls to csv and deleted the first 16 rows to get to the "main table"

I replaced the , with | to match your file setup

I created your table in my DBA database in the dbo schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report_RAW]( [Contract Number] [varchar](max) NULL, [Contract Name] [varchar](max) NULL, [Organization Type] [varchar](max) NULL, [Plan ID] [varchar](max) NULL, [Segment ID] [varchar](max) NULL, [Plan Name] [varchar](max) NULL, [Plan Type] [varchar](max) NULL, [Plan Geographic Name] [varchar](max) NULL, [State(s)] [varchar](max) NULL, [Plan Enrollment] [varchar](max) NULL, [Special Needs Plan Type] [varchar](max) NULL, [Specialty Diseases] [varchar](max) NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

I ran BCP to copy the data from the csv I created from the zip contents and it successfully imported the data to the table created in DBA

```
bcp "[DBA].[dbo].[SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report_RAW]" in  "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\SNP_2019_02.csv" -c -t"|" -T -S "bi-server"
```

[image: bcp results]

Comment: ? Not sure I follow what your asking the table is empty. Why do you want me to select from Empty table? The data is in the file and I want to move it to the Table? Also the file name is already in double quotes

Comment: I've revised the answer sorry for the confusion. @LeoTorres

Comment: I did what you suggested and same thing. I also removed the space between F and 2 and same thing.

Comment: Wow I am surprised. Did you try exactly what I put in the answer? @LeoTorres can you provide a sample file or example data so I can investigate further?

Comment: I have sample file not sure I have rights to attach file

Comment: "Scrub" the file and put some dummy values so its safe to share.

Comment: This is public data its on the CMS website let me locate link. But it would be easier to attach

Comment: I figured when I saw "CMS" in the bcp command. If you can give me the name of the data set or a link from cms.gov I'd be all set I work with a lot of CMS data.

Comment: @LeoTorres; Also were you just running the BCP command from command prompt and these issues came up after you started to use xp_cmdshell to run it from tSQL? I wondering if this could be as simple as the SQL Server service account just needs access to where the file is and were just getting a misleading error.

Comment: Cool. if you work alot with CMS Data love to chat and share ideas. the link is here

Comment: https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Downloads/2019/Feb/SNP-2019-02.zip

Comment: The .zip has a xls I assume your converting this to a csv and then trying to use that with bcp?

Comment: And is the requirement to load the rows from the main table from Rows 17 down to the end of the file? There is some nonsense data that would cause parsing issues on rows 1-16.

Comment: And does [CMS_Data].[dat].[SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report_RAW] have these columns:

Contract Number Contract Name Organization Type Plan ID Segment ID Plan Name Plan Type Plan Geographic Name State(s) Plan Enrollment Special Needs Plan Type Specialty Diseases

Comment: Correct yes i forgot to mention that. I converted the file to pipe delimited with python script . I have a script that downloaded all the files on that page going back to 2007. The pipe delimited file looks fine to me. Could there be a problem with file?

Comment: Here is the table script

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dat].[SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report_RAW](
 [Contract Number] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Contract Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Organization Type] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Plan ID] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Segment ID] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Plan Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Plan Type] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Plan Geographic Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [State(s)] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Plan Enrollment] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Special Needs Plan Type] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Specialty Diseases] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: I'm going to guess something is malformed in your file. I'm going to manually delete whats in rows 1-16 convert it to a CSV and change the , to a | and see what happens with bcp loading rows 17 (what becomes row 1 now) to the end of the file.

Comment: i removed the first 17 lines so the header is the top row. I tried to import file with only 2 rows. Thinking that the file was malformed and still nothing with 2 rows. really getting annoyed with this issue. Its been 3 days now and not making progress.

Comment: @LeoTorres I got it working with this:

I created your table in DBA database in dbo schema
I download the zip and converted the xls to csv and removed the first 16 rows
I ran this and it succeeded 

bcp "[DBA].[dbo].[SNP_2019_02_Special Needs Plan Report_RAW]" in  "C:\Users\someuser\Desktop\SNP_2019_02.csv" -c -t"|" -T -S "bi-server"

Comment: Yes i used your last statement and it worked thank you... Love to  share ideas on  CMS data. I have scripts that scrape all the CMS data on that site.  Any way to reach you?

Comment: I got it please go ahead and delete email so you dont get spammed